# Clickable header on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, header

I don't have clickable header on my website. I want redirect to home page when I click on header. I don't know how the code should look to make it work.

This is my page-header.php code:

```
<div class="entry-header">
        <div class="cv-outer">
        <div class="cv-inner">
            <div class="header-logo">

                <?php 

                if ( has_custom_logo() ) :

                    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
                    $custom_logo    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );

                ?>

                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>" class="logo-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url(  $custom_logo[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>">
                </a>

                <?php else : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>"><?php echo bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php if ( display_header_text() ) : ?>
                <br>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think I should add somethink here but I don't know PHP enough:

```
if ( has_custom_logo() ) :

                $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
                $custom_logo    = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );

            ?>

            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>" class="logo-img">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url(  $custom_logo[0] ); ?>" alt="<?php esc_attr( bloginfo('name') ); ?>">
            </a>

            <?php else : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') ); ?>"><?php echo bloginfo( 'title' ); ?></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( display_header_text() ) : ?>
            <br>
            <p class="site-description"><?php echo bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

In additional I show you source of website in browser:

[browser website source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqyyz.png)

All advice will be invaluable!

Comment: Can you explain what part of the code is not working? You can [edit] the question to clarify this.

Comment: My header on website isn't clickable. I want redirect to home page when I click on header. I don't know how the code should look to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I personally would put the PHP code in the definition for CV-Outer div.

```
     <?PHP
         if (has_custom_logo()) {
               echo "<div class='cv-outer clickHeader'>" + PHP_EOL;
         } else {
               echo "<div class='cv-outer'>" + PHP_EOL;
         }
     ?>
```

Then, just add an onclick handler to your javascript for the clickHeader class to redirect to the proper URL.

If you need to keep the custom logo from the PHP code, just leave it there, delete the bit that has the URL.

Basically, the problem is that the hyperlink isn't clickable because it has no size. Instead of messing with CSS to make it fit...I'd just remove it and use JS for the clickhandler...

Full HTML Code:

```
<div class="entry-header">
<?PHP
if (has_custom_logo()) {
    echo "<div class='cv-outer clickHeader'>" + PHP_EOL;
     } else {
    echo "<div class='cv-outer'>" + PHP_EOL;
     }
?>
<div class="cv-inner">
    <div class="header-logo">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Sample Javascript:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        var headers = document.getElementsByTagName('clickHeader');
        for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            var header = headers[i];
            header.onclick = function() {
                document.location.href="/";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can't save it, because is error in 4 line:

syntax error, unexpected 'cv' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: I changed this code but header isn't clickable. Need I change somethink more? If it's JS, can you show me how it should look like?

Sorry, I'm newbie in PHP, HTML and JS, that's why I have problem with easiest tasks.

Comment: Sure. Are you using *pure* JS, or Jquery, etc?

Comment: Ouhhh... I'm not sure. Is any place where can I check it for you?
If it's helps, my wordpress template name is Savona

Comment: I don't know why but when I edit page-header and add JS script, header isn't clickable ;/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the title is empty.

In the else clause, if there is no custom logo, then a link will be displayed inside with text. The link is there, but it is not clickable because there is no text inside the link.

Can you check if `bloginfo( 'title' )` is non-empty?

Another workaround would be to add a default picture that you know exists inside the link div, instead of text.

Comment: I can't set title in wordpress settings because I have that effect:

https://imgur.com/a/QDEJGun

Answer (score 0):

You just keep all header div in an Anchor element. Like below code

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
  <div class="cv-inner">
    <div class="header-logo">

    </div>
   </div>
</a>
```